# How to parse this single line Console input most efficiently

Tags: c#, console

I am trying to get the input from the user in a single Line with with [, ,] separators. Like this:

```
[Q,W,1] [R,T,3] [Y,U,9]
```

And then I will use these inputs in a function like this:

```
f.MyFunction('Q','W',1); // Third parameter will be taken as integer
f.MyFunction('R','T',3);
f.MyFunction('Y','U',9);
```

I thought I could do sth like:

```
    string input = Console.ReadLine();
    string input1 = input.Split(' ')[0];
    char   input2 = input.Trim(',') [0];
```

But it seems to repeat a lot.
What would be the most logical way to do this?

Comment: `string[] inputs = input.Split(' '); foreach (string item in inputs) // TODO: split on comma and call function`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes a regular expression really is the best tool for the job. Use a pattern that matches the input pattern and use `Regex.Matches` to extract all the possible inputs:

```
var funcArgRE = new Regex(@"\[(.),(.),(\d+)\]", RegexOptions.Compiled);

foreach (Match match in funcArgRE.Matches(input)) {
    var g = match.Groups;
    f.MyFunction(g[1].Value[0], g[2].Value[0], Int32.Parse(g[3].Value));
}
```

Comment: It's indeed more compact, but it's less readable imho.

Comment: This is how I'd do it. Waaay better than `String.Split()`. The only question is if he wants to allow more whitespace, and even then I might address it by preprocessing the string to remove ALL the whitespace before applying the expression.

Comment: @Mahmoud But much more tolerant of whitespace variation between the input phrases then using `Split`, and better at ignoring illegal input. Expecting a user to type in something exactly is a recipe for failure.

Comment: Depends on his requirements I'd say, but definitely it looks much more compact, and one liner is better I think for his problem version, for me, I focus more on readability of the code.

Comment: @Mahmoud I would argue the regex is more readable as well :) While I am a big fan of LINQ, parsing string input isn't its strong suit.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could use `LinQ to objects` functions and do something like this:

```
var inputs = input.Split(' ')
    .Select(x =>
        x.Replace("[", "")
         .Replace("]", ""))
    .Select(x => new UserInput(x))
    .ToList();

foreach(var userInput in inputs)
{
   f.MyFunction(userInput.A, userInput.B, userInput.Number);
}
```

// Somewhere else

```
public record UserInput
{
    public UserInput(string input)
    {
        //Do some kind of validation here and throw exception accordingly
        var parts = input.Split(',');

        A = parts[0][0];
        B = parts[1][0];
        Number = Convert.ToInt32(parts[2]);
    }

    public char A { get; init; }
    public char B { get; init; }
    public int Number { get; init; }
};
```

Or you could go further and implement "operator overloading" for the `UserInput` record and make it possible to implicitly convert from string to `UserInput`

Comment: Why would you do the `Replace` outside the `UserInput` - if you are encapsulating parsing in `UserInput` it should do all of it (and why is it a `record` and not a `class` - it just adds unnecessary overhead?)